# Showing $1+3\sqrt{-5}$ is irreducible but not prime.

Tags: field-theory, ideals, finite-fields, integral-domain

> Question:
>
> In $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \sqrt{-5} \ \right]$ show that $1+3\sqrt{-5}$ is irreducible but not prime.

Attempt:

Suppose $1+3\sqrt{-5} =\left ( a+b\sqrt{-5} \right )\cdot \left ( c+d\sqrt{-5} \right )$
Where $\left ( a+b\sqrt{-5} \right ), \left ( c+d\sqrt{-5} \right )$ are not units.
$\cdot \cdot \cdot$
I attempted without assuming that $\left ( a+b\sqrt{-5} \right ),\left ( c+d\sqrt{-5} \right )$ are not units.
Par for the course, the attempt did not span very far.

What is peculiar is that when I look at the definition of *irreducible*, there was no such condition requiring $\left ( a+b\sqrt{-5} \right ),\left ( c+d\sqrt{-5} \right )$ to be non-units.

> Recall: a non-zero element a in the integral domain D is called *irreducible* if a is not a unit and whenever $\exists b,c \in D$: $a=b \cdot c$ then either b or c is a unit.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I want to know why$\left ( a+b\sqrt{-5} \right ), \left ( c+d\sqrt{-5} \right )$ are assumed not to be units.

Comment: They are assumed to not be units because of the definition of irreducible: $x$ is irreducible if it cannot be written as $uv$ with $u,v$ both non-units. They assume that it's reducible (i.e. that it _can_ be written as such), and then derive a contradiction.

Comment: I suggest you look at the definition of irreducible once again

Answer (score 0):

The definition says: If $a=bc$ then at least one of $a,b$ is a unit.
Equivalently: It is not possible to write $a=bc$ with $a,b$ non-units.
So as proof strategy: Assume $a=bc$ with $b,c$ non-units and try to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Or otherwise equivalently assuming b and c are both units?